# Question regarding the impact of additional PTS firmware version to P2PE application and P2PE solution

Tags: pci-dss, firmware

I have a question regarding the impact of additional PTS firmware version to P2PE application and P2PE solution.

Is additional PTS approved firmware version subject to addition of POI device type?
Because the term "POI device type" was defined as below on the P2PE Glossary.

POI device type: Unique instance (combination) of a model name, hardware and **firmware number**.

For instance, there is a PTS approved POI device (Firmware #1.1.x) supported by a P2PE application and a P2PE solution provider. If the POI device obtains additional PTS approval by delta evaluation for its updated Firmware #1.2.x and will be supported by the P2PE application and the solution provider.
Does the P2PE application have to go through the process of delta change because it is subject to addition of POI device type?

Also, does the P2PE solution provider have to go through the process of designated change because it is subject to addition of POI device type and P2PE application version?